# D3.js bar chart Y-axis issue

Tags: d3.js

I created bar chart on network dataset. My dataset contains json format with different clients traffic. Each client has n number of records while showing bar chart we are displaying max traffic value in that n records. My question is that,I want to display the summation value of n records traffic over on bar for different clients.

```
My bar.html:
===========
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bartext {
font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#B5094C", "#CC66CC", "#FDCA11", "#3DB40D","#F672A9"]);

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10, "Mega Bytes");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("traffic.json", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.client_ip; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total_traffic/1024; })]);

svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform",
                    "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis).append("text")
                    .attr("x", 879).attr("y", 15)
                    .style("text-anchor", "bottom").text("Clients");

            svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis).append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)").attr("y", 6).attr("dy",
                            ".71em").style("text-anchor", "end").text(
                            "Mega Bytes");

            svg.selectAll("bar").data(data).enter().append("rect").style(
                    "fill", function(d) {
                        return color(d.client_ip);
                    }).attr("class", "bar").attr("x", function(d) {
                return x(d.client_ip);
            }).attr("width", x.rangeBand()).attr("y", function(d) {
                return y(d.total_traffic/1024);
            }).attr("height", function(d) {
                return height - y(d.total_traffic/1024);
            });

  var yTextPadding = 20;
svg.selectAll(".bartext")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.attr("class", "bartext")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("dx", -3) // padding-right
.attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
.attr("text-anchor", "end") //
.attr("fill", "black")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.client_ip)+130; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.total_traffic/1024)-12;})
.text(function(d){
     return d.total_traffic/1024;
});

});

function type(d) {
  d.total_traffic = +d.total_traffic;
  return d;
}

</script>

My traffic.json file:
======================
[ { "client_ip" : "1.128.148.243" , "timestamp" : "1341619346000" , "total_traffic" : 0} , { "client_ip" : "1.128.148.243" , "timestamp" : "1341619346039" , "total_traffic" : 1} , { "client_ip" : "1.128.148.243" , "timestamp" : "1341619346153" , "total_traffic" : 3} , { "client_ip" : "1.128.148.243" , "timestamp" : "1341619346175" , "total_traffic" : 4} , { "client_ip" : "92.168.4.53" , "timestamp" : "1341619346216" , "total_traffic" : 6} , { "client_ip" : "92.168.4.53" , "timestamp" : "1341619346219" , "total_traffic" : 7} , { "client_ip" : "92.168.4.53" , "timestamp" : "1341619346310" , "total_traffic" : 8} , { "client_ip" : "92.168.4.53" , "timestamp" : "1341619346320" , "total_traffic" : 10} , { "client_ip" : "192.168.7.23" , "timestamp" : "1341619346342" , "total_traffic" : 11} , { "client_ip" : "192.168.7.23" , "timestamp" : "1341619346372" , "total_traffic" : 13} , { "client_ip" : "192.168.7.23" , "timestamp" : "1341619346380" , "total_traffic" : 14} , { "client_ip" : "192.168.7.23" , "timestamp" : "1341619346392" , "total_traffic" : 16} , { "client_ip" : "98.53.1.76" , "timestamp" : "1341619346404" , "total_traffic" : 17} , { "client_ip" : "98.53.1.76" , "timestamp" : "1341619346415" , "total_traffic" : 19} , { "client_ip" : "98.53.1.76" , "timestamp" : "1341619346450" , "total_traffic" : 20} , { "client_ip" : "98.53.1.76" , "timestamp" : "1341619346462" , "total_traffic" : 22}]
```

Can anyone please suggest on this issue ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use on each user:

```
d.values.reduce(function(sum, d){
            return sum + d.amount;
        },0)
```

[Here's reduce documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).-

Comment: Can you please explain, where should I implement these code.